# Sharing 2d string array from activity two to activity one

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent

I have a problem when trying to share some string array from activity two to activity one. One I do is that I edit (fill) 
the array in activity two multiple times and in activity one I just choose the row. I want completely filled array at the end. Ive tried with intent and startactivityforresult but with no success. Is there a way other than creating a text file for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**in the Activity2 class:**

```
List<String> yourStringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
//put some data to your array list
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity1.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("name", yourStringArrayList);
Activity2.this.startActivity(intent);
```

**in the Activity1 class:**

```
List<String> yourStringArrayList;
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent !=null && intent.hasExtra("name"))
  yourStringArrayList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("name");
```

Comment: I have 2d array so for now I am unable to use putStringArrayListExtra

Comment: U can use bundle. putSerializable("array", array2d) and get via 
String[][] array = (String[][]) bundle.getSerializable("array");